# IBM MOBILEFIRST CLI-Error While Deploying

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

This query is regarding IBM MobileFirst CLI 6.3.0 Version. While running the deploy command We are getting error as below. Unable to figure out the root cause for the same. Please help

> BUILD FAILED
>   /opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:403:
>   Element  inside , attribute
>   'warFile' is invalid for use with : It
>   does not end with '.war':
>   /users/wasadm/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/.nfs0000000033c12d6600000221
>
> Total time: 0 secondsError: Build process failed. Please check the
>   stack above for details.
>
> Starting server worklight. Server worklight start failed. Check server
>   logs for details.
>   /users/wasadm/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/bin/server: line 744:
>   22493 Aborted                 (core dumped) "${JAVA_CMD}" "$@" >
>   "${JAVA_CMD_LOG}" 2>&1 Error: The MobileFirst server failed to start.
>   The port may be in use by another instance of a running server, or the
>   server may not exist. "

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are failing because, as the error message says, the port is already occupied.

Make sure Eclipse is not running.
Also try killing the Java process and then try to start the server from the command line.

See here for more: [IBM Mobilefirst CLI - Server start issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073927/ibm-mobilefirst-cli-server-start-issue)

Comment: After Killing the process, I am able to proceed but failing during deploying with below error, Can u please help in this. Comments logged in parts

Comment: "Runtime-status:
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/app2/test/HelloNew
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=10.66.117.197

Comment: mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task runtime-status
Buildfile: /opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml "

Comment: To be clear, the mobilefirst-cli is a developer tool only.  It is not appropriate to use it to deploy to standalone MobileFirst servers.  There is a separate command line tool for admin/devops to accomplish this.  I see in your original post that the user is "wasadm", which is making me suspicious.  Be ensure you are not mixing environments, which would also describe whay you had conflicting ports initially.