# IBM Mobilefirst - server start issue

Tags: server, ibm-mobilefirst

I try to play with the IBM Mobilefirst platform, but I can not pass this issue.
I thoght it was a problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073927/ibm-mobilefirst-cli-server-start-issue), but it seems it's not.

Everything it is ok, but when I try to run :

```
$ mfp start
```

in my terminal , I get this :

```
Initializing MobileFirst Console.
/home/me/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/bin/server: 757: /home/me/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/bin/server: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found

Error: The MobileFirst server failed to start. The port may be in use by another instance of a running server, or the server may not exist.
```

What can I do to pass this problem?

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME set? Does it point to a JDK or a JRE? Does the file it mentions exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error 99% of the time means that you have a process running - kill the Java process using the Activity Monitor.

Additionally, what is your mfp version? use "mfp -v"

Try:

1. Uninstalling it using the uninstaller from /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/Uninstaller
2. delete the "ibm" folder by using "rm -rf ~/.ibm"
3. Download the latest CLI from IBM Fix Central which contains several CLI fixes and try again